# Where can I find the OTA update file?

Tags: file-system, ota-update, cache, motorola-droid-bionic

I'm trying to locate the zip file that contains the OTA update for my Droid Bionic.  Right now, its failing to update, and every time it fails it deletes the file and I need to re-download it (takes a long time).  I was hoping to save off the update so I could try a few things on my phone and try the update.  I read online its somewhere in a /cache directory, however I dont see anything at all when I mount it to the PC and do a search for cache or even "*.zip".  Does anyone know how I can find the zip file?  Maybe I need to change the PC settings or something to search for it (I have changed the folder settings to view hidden files and system files).

Comment: `/cache` is typically a separate partition on your device, which wouldn't be mountable by a PC via USB. You'd probably need to first use a file manager (or shell, or something) on your device to move the file from `/cache` to your external storage. You probably need root for this, though.

Comment: @eldarerathis - Thanks for the response.  I have rooted my phone and downloaded `"ES File Explorer File Manager"` from the market.  In `/cache`, all I see is a file called `Blur_Vesion.5.9.905.XT875.Verizon.en.US.zip` which was the last update.  The new one I would expect to be something like `6.7.246.XT875.Verizon.en.US.zip`, but there isnt anything like that there.  The file is about 368 MB.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Hm, not sure. I would have expected the newest OTA to be there as well, and I don't know of any other places offhand that it may have ended up.

Comment: I had a similar issue when updating from 902 to 905. I followed the two pages of instructions in the below-linked article to get me to 905:
http://androidadvices.com/update-motorola-droid-bionic-latest-59905-firmware/ Good luck!

Comment: @eldarerathis - Well I guess that file is the update for ICS.  So if you want to post it as an answer I will accept it.  Not sure why the decided to mislabel the file, but I just got it working and that was the file that got me to ICS, thx!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two pieces of ground I want to cover here:

1. `/cache` is typically a separate partition on your device, which wouldn't be mountable by a PC via USB, which is why that isn't working. The USB connection generally accesses a directory named "sdcard" (or similar) which is used as an external storage device, although this storage area doesn't have to be physically external to the device (it may just be a partition named `/sdcard` rather than a physical card).
2. If the OTA is in `/cache` then you should be able to find it with a file explorer or shell on your device. Once you've found it, you could simply move the file from `/cache` to your external storage and then copy it over USB. You'll need root in order to access `/cache`, though. There are a number of file explorers that support root access, but I personally use [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop).

Answer (score 1):

For Lenovo ,the location for Downloaded Update file is : **internal storage > LenovoOTA** or **sdcard0/LenovoOTA**  folder

**after** download completes **mount** to pc ,copy then **execute** on mobile/device otherwise file 'll be deleted after update

Answer (score 1):

My device is HTC One M7 
I managed to find the OTA by doing a dumpsys | grep .zip

I was already in a adb shell su session as the file was being downloaded,(after I exited and re-entered the shell and tried to run the dumpsys command I couldn't find it. I'm guessing dumpsys works on a temporary log.)

eventually I found it in the 
 /data/data/com.android.providers.downloads/cache 
folder

I managed to copy it to /sdcard but it wouldn't show up in Windows Explorer until I unplugged and re-plugged the USB cable in.

I guess Windows doesn't refresh the folder/directory index (or something) to see new files created in there

Answer (score 1):

For samsung device `/data/fota`

Search for `fota` folder.

In that folder, you will find update.zip

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can flash an FXZ rom image for your current version or later. The benefit of that is that it doesn't matter what state your phone is in or if its missing bloatware that the OTA update requires.

Things you need:

- FXZ image for the desired version (google search for it)
- RSDLite (google search rsdlite 5.7 download)
- Motorola device drivers (found on motorola's site)
- USB cable

Answer (score 0):

I found the OTA package in following location

```
/data/data/com.lenovo.ota/app_otapackages/
```

For my Lenovo K3 Note

Answer (score 0):

for Lineage or /e/ these are saved at `/data/lineageos_updates/`, if you can enable an adb root shell you can pull files from there.