# Is there a way to get detailed information on why an OTA update fails?

Tags: updates, rom-flashing, logging, ota-update

I'm trying to figure out why my OTA update is failing.  I have unrooted my Droid Bionic, and did a factory reset.  It starts to update, then reaches about a quarter of the way and stops.  It just reboots without the update.

I'm trying to figure out how to save off the update file in another question [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32205/where-can-i-find-the-ota-update-file).

Once I've done that, I was wondering if there is a way to get a verbose output or a text file log of what the failure was during the update.  Does anyone know if this is possible?  Is it not shown and logged so people can't figure out what the checks are for doing the OTA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, found the answer [here](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/droid-4-general-discussion/220910-ota-update-droid-4-august-18th-6.html)

> When you start the update process it loads that screen with the android character and the yellow progress bar, as soon as that screen shows up press both vol up and vol down at the same time and it will switch to verbose mode where it will show each step of the install process. When it fails it will typically display a directory and apk file name.

Time to figure out what `logwrapper` is and why its out of date.