# Can I install software update after flashing custom ROM?

Tags: rom-flashing

I have a MOTOX XT1052 and have flashed a custom ROM. I got a Sytem Update and downloded it. To install, its going to TWRP interface and I am not able to install the update. So, I have rebooted the device to go to skip from the TWRP mode. But, the device keeps on reeboting automatically. Now, I have flashed the custom ROM once again and just postponding the system update installation.

Please help me to recover the phone from this issue.

Comment: If it is an official update from Motorola: No you can't, unless you go back to root. If it is an update for the ROM itself then yes you can.

Comment: Yes, it is an update from Motorola. Please help me to skip the update installation forever or to revert to the stock rom.

Comment: Well to revert to stock, check out XDA for your stock ROM. To get rid of it you need to find and delete `Update.zip` on your device (I'm not sure where) and then accept the update, it will boot into TWRP as normal, fail and then never be seen again!  See here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32205/where-can-i-find-the-ota-update-file

Comment: What if you unroot? Maybe then you could update your phone.