# The Android OS is being updated with Internet turned off - how can it be?

Tags: wi-fi, updates, internet, mobile-data

A phone has mobile data turned off.

No wifi antennae is connected. We were in the wood, on the hill, minimally 3 km from the nearest village. The nearest, higher hill, has a mobile antennae. So, the mobile signal was on. Even if there was a wifi antennae, I hadn't connected to it.

So, obviously, no Internet connection was active.

But the phone suddenly decided to update the Android OS. And started to download the update. It was even finished - in 5 hours - without internet being on. How could it be downloaded? Will I have to pay for those data? (the phone has no prepaid Internet)

The device is ASUS ZenFone 3 Max.

Comment: Can you see the update download progress percentage?

Comment: You can check the OTA updates location and see the time https://android.stackexchange.com/q/32205/131553

Comment: @MANI Yes, I have seen that progress (about 5 hours), and it was even finished - without internet being on.

Comment: @beeshyams The phone was(and is) apart from Internet for 2 weeks uninterruptedly.... I will try to check.

Comment: I honestly don't see how this is possible if you had mobile data turned off (meaning actually disabled, not just not paid for) and WiFi off. If mobile data was on it could have downloaded the updated on 2G (which would also explain the 5 hours time). Does your Data Usage in Settings show anything recently for WiFi or Mobile Data?

Comment: @acejavelin I thought that is impossible too, intil I saw it by my own eyes.

Comment: OK, but did you look what it actually used? Your Data Usage in Settings should give you some idea of what used data (and what type) recently.

Comment: @acejavelin Data usage is off. Any try to reach the Internet results in message, that there are no Internet connection. I think,  beeshyams gave an interesting idea - downloaded somewhen before, but installed now. But then I don't understand the 5 hours installation.

Comment: I would agree with beeshyams, that makes the most sense... but I still would check your Data Usage in Settings, the fact your are saying it's off is telling me you don't understand what I am asking. On a "normal" Android device in Settings - Data Usage there is a graph and list of apps that have been using Mobile Data (and WiFi if advanced is turned on), you should be able to see if data was used during the last few days (or that window of time).

Comment: @acejavelin Oh, thank you. The problem though is that I will have the phone in my hands on Saturday only. :-(... - It is one of my daughter's and she is in the country now. But we'll try.