# EMUI 8: Where is the downloaded OTA located?

Tags: huawei, 8.0-oreo, emui

I downloaded the latest version of EMUI 8 for my Huawei Nova 2i (RNE-L22), the file size is 3GB.

Before installing the update, I'm planning to do a factory reset but that means I will need to re-download the update. The problem is I have a very limited internet connection, so I wanted to move the file into my SD-Card and flash it later.

I couldn't find where the file is located, anyone knows where it is?

Anyway, I downloaded the update by navigating into the `Settings` > `About Phone` > `System Update`.

Comment: See [this related question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32205/where-can-i-find-the-ota-update-file). If the location is Huawei specific inside /data/data then you don't have access on un-rooted devices. In any way it does not matter if you first do the factory reset or afterwards. Just to be sure I would remove all accounts in Android settings -> accounts so that you can do a factory reset later without running into FRP (if the device does not boot up correctly after upgrade). Therefore if you don't want to redownload the update apply it before doing the factory reset.

Comment: I don't understand what's with Huawei. This should be easy and should be accessible with a root or unrooted device. Anyway, I just update it and do a factory reset later.